# How to access the DOM element from template decided by ng-if

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

All:

I am new to AngularJS directive template, right now one thing confuses me is how to get the DOM element which decided by ng-if in directive template.

For example:

```
app.directive("dir", function(){
    return {
        restrict:"AE",
        scope: {},
        controller: function(){},
        templateUrl: "templates/testpostlink.html",
        compile: function(){
            return {
                pre: function(){
                },
                post:function(scope, EL, attrs){
                     // Here I am wondering how to get that div (let say scope.show is true)
                }
            };
        }// end of compile
    };
});
```

And template testpostlink.html is:

```
<div ng-if="show">Show Content</div>
```

What I want to do is get this div element and adjust style to it. But in post function, there is still no that element generated.

Could anyone help with this?

Thanks

Comment: You can adjust the style with `ng-class` which uses an expression. If some expression evaluates to true, then it will use the css class you provide which contains your style. `ng-class="{activeClass: show}"`.

Comment: It is simple - you can't access that element. The element might not exist yet. The best way would be if the element itself will tell your directive that it is has just been linked... you can use `ngInit` for that. Or better - if you don't mind having that element in the DOM you can use `ngShow` instead of `ngIf`.

Comment: This is a jQuery way of thinking, if you want to modify the style of the element you should use the directives angular offers, such as ngClass, ngStyle or if required a custom directive. What sort of stuff would you like to do with it?

Comment: @ALL THanks guys, I think I will just change design( kinda understand angularJS a little better, it turns out that I need to plan and structure it ahead of time.) and use ng-style

Comment: Still a good exercise to understand the load order and how to work with directives. Have a look at my answer. As discussed above, if you're only looking for a style then the ng-style directive may solve your problem easily.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you are doing wrong is you are not passing in a show variable so the ng-if is not showing. Secondly, use the post link function to add styles to your element.

http://plnkr.co/edit/PqXg6e?p=preview

```
<!-- pass in show variable -->
<div dir show="showFromCtrl"></div>

app.directive("dir", function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict:"AE",
    // needed to pass in show variable
    scope: { show: "=" },
    templateUrl: 'testpostlink.html',
    compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
      return {
        post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
          // access element and add styles in post link fn
          iElement.css('color', 'red');
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks, but your example only apply style to root element, but when it comes to the element which under it and decided by ng-if, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, albeit a little annoying. Basically, you're going to add $watch to your scope for the value change and then reset the el every time.

```
app.directive("dir", function(){
    return {
        restrict:"AE",
        scope: {
            ngIf: "=" //add a two way binding so we can watch the ngIf
        },
        controller: function(){},
        templateUrl: "templates/testpostlink.html",
        compile: function(){
            return {
                pre: function(){
                },
                post:function(scope, EL, attrs){
                    // El should be [comment] when ngIf is false

                    var realEl; // store our real element. This will be destroyed and recreated every time ngIf changes

                    scope.$watch('ngIf', function(val){
                        if (val) {
                            //store our new real element
                            realEl = El.next();
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
        }// end of compile
    };
});
```